# How can I make this button toggle the position of a servo?

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, button, switch, debounce

I am trying to make something so when I press the button it sets the position of the servo to 50 and then when I press it again, it sets it to 150. The button is momentary not a toggle switch. This is what I have come up with so far. I would also like to account for button bounce. Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo

// variables will change:
int pos = 0; // variable to store the servo position
int buttonState = 0; // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int button_mode = 1; // Variable for the button's current state.
// button_mode = 1 when the button is up, and 0 when the button is pressed.
// This variable is 'static' and persists because it is declared outside a function.

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(8); // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize the Serial port at 9600 baud.
  pinMode(9,INPUT); // Set Digital pin 9 to an input so it can monitor the button.
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(9);
  if ((digitalRead(9) == LOW) && (button_mode == 1)) {
    // Check Digital pin 9 to see if it's pressed.
    pos = 150; //set servo position variable to 150
    myservo.write(pos); //set servo postion to 'pos'
    delay(1000); // wait 1 second
    button_mode = 0; // Button was up before, but is pressed now. Set the button to pressed
    Serial.println("Button has been pressed."); // and report that to the serial monitor.
  } else if ((digitalRead(9) == HIGH) && (button_mode == 0)) {
    pos = 50;
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(1000);
    button_mode = 1; // Button was down before, but is released now. Set the button to
    Serial.println("Button has been released"); // released and report that to the serial monitor.
  }
  delay(100); //small delay to account for button bounce
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not well structured. Here is what I would do:

```
if (button_pressed()) { //test to see if button is pressed
  button_state +=1; //increment button
  if (button_stat & 0x01) {//if lsb set
    myservo.write(SERVO_POS1); //set servo position 1
  } else {
    myservo.write(SERVO_POS2); //set servo position 2
  }
}
```

You can debounce if you wish in button_pressed().

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
int angles[2] = {0,180}
bool state = 0;
```

then:

```
if(button == PRESSED)
  state = !state;
```

finnally, to control the servo:

```
Servo.write(angles[state]);
```